# React - Parcel - build failed. Error: Could not resolve module "self-published/parcel-swc.darwin-x64.node"

Tags: reactjs, parceljs, build-error

It's coming across to me one awkward issue.
I made this project a while ago with React using Parcel to build.
Now after a couple of months I tried to start the project and it gave me some errors building.
I download again the project from the repository and the parcel started to build again for a couple of hours and the same error came up again. Once again, I download the project from the repository and it start to run again, but without any change made in the project...it started to give again the same Build Error.
Did some of you had this issue?

[Parcel Build failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSgCp.png)

[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KffD.png)

Thank you!

Comment: I see your project is pinned to parcel version `2.0.0-rc0`, which is quite old and a pre-release version - do you see the same errors when you upgrade `parcel`, `@parcel/transformer-image`, and `@parcel/transformer-sass` to the latest `2.5.0` release?

Comment: @AndrewStegmaier thank you for your answer! 
Just updated and now I got this new error.
[New Error](https://postimg.cc/cr8N6wK6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This answer is in response to the [New Error](https://postimg.cc/cr8N6wK6) you get after upgrading the project to parcel 2.5.0)

When you run `parcel index.html`, you'll be invoking the version of parcel that's installed globally, not the one locally specified by `package.json`. The error your getting is what I'd expect if the global version was still `2.0.0-rc0` (released August 2021) was run and tried to use the latest version of `@parcel/config-default` (installed in your project), because [compressor plugin support](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/6776) was added in September 2021.

From the original screenshots, it looks like you already have a "start" command in your `package.json`...

```
{
   "scripts": {
       "start": "parcel index.html"
   }
}
```

Invoke it by running `npm run start` - this will use the version of parcel (2.5.0) installed there.

Comment: Hi @AndrewSetgmaier, thank you so much for all your patience and explanation! Indeed, it makes all the sense, but something continuous wrong and I'm finding quite hard for a solution to fix it:
['Error: Got unexpected null'](https://postimg.cc/QByLcLbv)

Comment: That's not an error I've seen before. Could you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), perhaps as a github repo?

Comment: Sure! Here goes the guithub repo! Thank you!
https://github.com/JonsMendi/myMovies-client/tree/dev

Comment: I fixed parcel builds in [this PR](https://github.com/JonsMendi/myMovies-client/pull/3) see the description for details. I didn't see the same errors you did at first, but I tested these changes, and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and incredible efficiency! for some reason, even after updating the parcel, it didn't change the version in the package.json...and as you explained it may have been that and the gap in "main: index.js" that I was unaware of in the parcel documentation itself .
So far everything seems to be working perfectly!
Thank you so much for your help and your time!

Comment: Glad it worked! If you're happy with the answer, would you mind hitting the "accept" button so others will know?

Comment: Definitely!! Thank you so much again!